# Python pandas dataframe: Is it possible to have rows in dataframe with different number of columns(column length)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two csv files where each row in one file is compared with all rows in another file and if row matches(based on some unique column in both rows), i'm creating a new row in third csv file where each row in this third file contains some values in the cell.

I'm using pandas dataframe for this as i can first create an empty dataframe and then add values into it and then at last use dataframe.to_csv() method to print the content of the dataframe to csv file(third file).

**The problem statement that i have is, based on condition like if some condition is true then i need to have/print only 522 columns in one row and if some condition is false then i need to have/print 621 columns on another row in the third file.**

Currently, always the third file contains 621 columns(because i have initialized dataframe as pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0,621), dtype=object))) irrespective of the condition whether its true or false but i need to have above mentioned behavior.

Comment: Hey buddy, please provide a textual example of your first two dataframes and an example of your 3rd dataframe which replicates your logic Have a read of [ask]

Comment: No. DataFrames are 2-D rectangles, so you would require either `NaN` in column that do not overlap, or you could consider a long format with a MultiIndex,

Comment: @ALollz Could you provide some more information on the possible solution. Eventually i need to have only 522 columns in a row (commas not exceeding more than 521 when you open the csv file in notepad++) if some condition is true otherwise 621 columns i need to print .